# Unable to execute DX

Tags: android, intellij-idea, desktop

please can anyone help me with next error?

*Error:Android Dex: [android] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Dex: [android] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/Application$ApplicationType;
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)*

**I Am attaching also screenshots from project settings:**

Thank you very much!

[image: Compilation Error]

[image: Core Structure]

[image: Android Structure]

[image: Project Structure]